# True or False $|P(X)|=|X^X|$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

True or False :

$|P(X)|=|X^X|$ (cardinality)

$X$ is an infinite set.

I think it's true becuase it works for $\aleph_0$ and $\aleph$
but I don't know how to prove it in general case.

Help please ?

Comment: There is a 1-1 correspondence between $\{0,1\}^X$ and $\mathscr P(X)$.  So I don't think your hypothesis is even true for $X = \{0,1,2\}$.

Comment: This question would benefit from added context, and will likely be closed otherwise. For example, simply telling us where you got the problem from or explaining your proof for $\aleph_0$ would be a big step forward! (For further feedback/help with asking questions, you can ask [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43593/constructive-feedback).)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any two cardinals $\kappa, \mu$, with $2 \le \kappa, 1 \le \mu$ and at least one of them infinite, you have

$$\max(\kappa, 2^\mu) \le \kappa^\mu \le \max (2^\kappa, 2^\mu).$$

Hence if $X$ is infinite of cardinal $\kappa$, you have

$$2^\kappa = \vert \mathcal P(X) \vert \le \vert X^X\vert = \vert X \vert^{\vert X \vert} = \kappa^\kappa \le 2^\kappa$$

proving **that the result you're looking for is true if the cardinal of $X$ is infinite.**